# Dijkstra implementation in CPP using priority_queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm and I'm having some trouble.

```
void Graph::Dijkstra(int source)
{
    // Initialize single source
    [...]

    // Initialize a priority queue with all vertices
    [...]

    // Main loop
    while (!Queue.empty())
    {
        int u = Queue.top();
        Queue.pop();

        // Relax the edges
        [...]
    }
}
```

After the source vertex, my code always chooses a vertex with infinite (100000) distance, even though there are other vertices with non infinte distance.

I though since the priority queue has the pointers to my vertices, it would update every time I changed a vertex's distance (v.d).

Comment: There are so many questions and answers about this topic around here (just check the **Related** section at the right side). Research a bit more thoroughly before asking please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`priority_queue` tries to maintain its invariant on a `pop`. You are relaxing the vertices after the `pop`. Make the following change :

```
while (!Queue.empty())
    {
        Vertex *u = Queue.top();

        list<Edge>::iterator i;
        for (i=u->adj.begin(); i!=u->adj.end(); ++i)
        {
            Vertex *v = &vertices[(*i).to];
            Relax(u,v,(*i).w);
        }

        Queue.pop();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. I don't know why I assumed the queue would mantain its invariant at all times.